# Mobile phone - Receive an SMS from MySQL

Tags: android

I had read a lot of posts. But I still confuse what should I use. I'm developing an Android application school project.

The user can purchase a ticket from my application and the user's phone will be receiving text from the server. I had read through the [C2DM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Cloud_to_Device_Messaging_Service), but I don't know if it is suitable to use in this application. The Free SMS gateway has a hard time finding it. Is there a solution?

Comment: C2DM would be overkill in my opinion for this scenario. SMS would be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have SMS module already running on the site, C2DM would be more feasible, I guess.

You should also consider the constraint that push notification (or even simple polling) will need data network available. However, using SMS service would probably mean that there will be extra expense. Both methods will need server-side running, so that's a draw.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Twilio's API](http://www.twilio.com/api) if you don't want to setup a gateway.

Comment: Twilio is super easy & the documentation is great.

Answer (score 1):

You must take the SMS Gateway package from SMS Gateway website and use their HTTP API to send SMSes directly through your application...

In India, SMS gateways are really affordable, and you should not go to any free service, because they are not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

There are many options for an SMS gateway.

You can either setup your own or use a third-party provider. If you go with the later option, you will have to search for providers in your country. They will give you access to their API which gives you access to their SMS gateway. Multiple account options are available so choose the one that suits you.

If you want to setup your own gateway [NowSMS](http://www.nowsms.org/) is a very good option and it is very cheap as well. It has lots of integration examples and an API to send and receive SMS messages. Their compatibility with various GSM modems is very good as well. It even works with handsets if you have one plugged in. So if you have an old GSM handset lying around, you can use that as the modem with NowSMS. Read their documentation to see what models work.

[Kannel](http://www.kannel.org/) do an open source free gateway.

Good luck.